# Lotusscript WSDL Object variable not set on XSD_HOLDER output parms

Tags: wsdl, lotusscript, lotus

We have the following code after importing a WSDL:

```vb
Class GofilexAPI_n0

    Sub NEW
        Dim s As NotesSession
        Set s = New NotesSession
    End Sub

    Sub AuthenticationToken(password As XSD_STRING, username As XSD_STRING, AuthenticationTokenResult As XSD_STRING_HOLDER , ResultCode As XSD_INT_HOLDER)
        Print password.getValueAsString()
        Print username.getValueAsString()
        ResultCode.Value.setValueFromString("1")
        AuthenticationTokenResult.Value.setValueFromString("foobr")
    End Sub

End Class
```

We get error "Object variable not set" on trying to set values to return variables AuthenticationTokenResult and ResultCode (last two lines of the sub).

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize (instantiate) the output values with `New`.

Otherwise they are `Nothing`. Calling methods for `Nothing` throws the error "Object variable not set".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Knut.
This is indeed the solution! We changed the code now as follows (because the parameters of the WSDL cannot be edited):

```vb
Class GofilexAPI_n0

    Sub NEW
        Dim s As NotesSession
        Set s = New NotesSession
    End Sub

    Sub AuthenticationToken(password As XSD_STRING, username As XSD_STRING, AuthenticationTokenResult As XSD_STRING_HOLDER , ResultCode As XSD_INT_HOLDER)
        Print password.getValueAsString()
        Print username.getValueAsString()
        Dim testding As New Xsd_string             <-------
        testding.Setvaluefromstring("foobar")     <-------
        Set AuthenticationTokenResult.Value = testding    <----------
    End Sub
End Class
```

Apparently it is necessary to dim the Xsd_string as a new Xsd_string and set the value of this first, only then it's possible to set the Xsd_String_Holder value.